# How can prevent to save 2 same object in same time in my data base? and how I can test this version works correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, account, accountmanager

We hava a gate that every vehicle submit his card and then we reduce his account.

Some times when gate officer open tow tab , two exchange save in our data base and vehicleAccount reduce twice and two same AccountExchange save in our data base .

Please help me to know how I can prevent to save 2 same Exchange in my data base.
how I can test this  version works correctly ?

I use version in my program like :
@Version private Long version = 0l
but this version doesnt increase when i change accounts in ui . all the version remain zero in all condition . I dont know why this problem occure?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe save a timestamp when writing to the database. Everytime before you change the record you can check if the last change is longer ago than 10 seconds - or whatever time difference is reasonable for your application.

Comment: yes , I did what you said. I have a event Time and when each transaction occur I check it by loaad last AccountExchange save in system and match whit it in sourceAccount and destinationAccount . but My problem is that 2 same transaction occur in same time and when i LoadLastAccountExchange any of them didnt save in system . I want to know how I can lock all math accountExchange until the end of transaction block in hibernet .

Comment: You wrote 'We hava a gate that every vehicle submit his card and then we reduce his account'. So it seems that every vehicle has an own id. If that is true there shouldn't be any problem because the account is unique somehow. And a vehicle is on gate A _or_ gate B. Please tell us more to understand the problem.

Comment: Hi. you say true every vehicle have a unique id and unique account . and every vehicle enter from a gate . but gate officers usally make a msitake and open tow tabs . and this two tab  indivitually done a transaction and change accounts in same time so every account change twice in a time.

Comment: Ok, another idea: do you have access to the tabs? Just prevent that the user is able to open two tabs at the same time.

Comment: yes, but its  difficult. beacuse we shoud check this offiser permanently But there is still the possibility that this problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an extra field in your table called "version". By default it is 0. Everytime you get an object you increment this version by one on your local object. When you want to save it you replace the object with ID = xxx and version = localversion-1. If you cannot find any object with this criteria someone else had saved it and therefor the version is incremented by 1 already.

Maybe Hibernate does include this already, but do not quote me on that.

Edit:
I use a @version annotation to make Hibernate handle it. But I don't know if any further configuration is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I add a version like bellow on my table . but now the problem is that , I have a lot of account in my data base that dont have any version . how I can define version for previous data ? now when I create an account , this account get a version in data base . but previous account dont have any version . I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: @Version
    private Long version = 0l;   this is my version.

Comment: Use a query on your table to set version to 0 for every tuple.

Comment: can you write a little code of this process please ?

Comment: I think @version annotation does it automatically . is it true ?

Comment: In my Entitys I have @Version as an annotation. You can try it. But ghen you should not handle the version number yourself. Simply add this annotation and Hibernate should handle it itself.

Comment: Does it require to declaring a version property in hbm.xml ? or just @version is enough ?